# Disabling Exceptions for MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, exception

I'm trying to disable exceptions completely in Visual Studio 2010, and to ensure that exception handling is disabled I have the following test:

```
class CompilerFlagsTestExceptionConstructor
{
public:
 CompilerFlagsTestExceptionConstructor() { throw std::exception("Exceptions Enabled"); }
 ~CompilerFlagsTestExceptionConstructor() { }
};

class CompilerFlagsTests : public CPPUNIT_NS::TestFixture
{
 CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE( CompilerFlagsTests );
  CPPUNIT_TEST( Test_NoExceptions );
 CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();
public:
 void Test_NoExceptions()
 {
  try
  {
   CompilerFlagsTestExceptionConstructor object;
  }
  catch(std::exception)
  {
   assert(!"Exceptions are enabled");
  }
 }
};
```

I have checked in the property pages that exception handling is disabled, and I've also disabled RTTI in all my projects. I have tried setting /EH to negative as well as omitting it from the command line.

Every time I run this test, it fails and it properly throws an exception

The reason I want to disable exception handling is because the target software is written for a target architecture that doesn't natively support exception handling and causes massive code bloat to accommodate the stack unwinding. The target architecture also has a maximum size of executable, so disabling exceptions shrinks code and also has a performance benefit. I want to disable exception handling on the windows version to ensure that the error handling to the target is working.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this test ever going to work? Is there some other way of forcing and testing that exceptions are disabled?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm...The nuclear option.  Will be interesting to see how this one turns out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure your test makes sense. What should the behavior be if exceptions are disabled? throw just becomes a no op? That's what the test suggests the behavior is.

I would expect for usefully disabling exceptions throw should be a compile error, or alternatively throwing with exceptions disabled should immediately terminate the process.

But this is a digression. MSVC will emit a call to _CxxThrowException for the throw syntax. If we define our own version of this we can make it dance to our song:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"
void __stdcall _CxxThrowException(void * pObject,
    _s__ThrowInfo const * pObjectInfo)
{

  printf("Nope\n");
}

struct a
{ };

int main()
{
  try {
  throw a();
  } catch(const a&) {
    printf("Caught an exception\n");
  }
}
```

This program prints out

> Nope

Of course this information is provided for purely entertainment purposes and with the context that you're doing this to match up with the error handling logic. I hope for example, that you don't intend to ship the windows version of the program to anyone like this.

Comment: Heh, no, I do not intend to ship a win32 version of this. I get a strange compilation error when I try to override this, saying that it is the second time the function has been declared. The odd part is that I have only one source file, and it is the first function I declare(before any header files are included). Reading the MSDN docs says that it is a compiler created function, and there appears to be no override.

Comment: You don't want to declare it, you just want to implement it. It's implicitly declared (like the _s__ThrowInfo type). You may have to do some fighting with the linker, this example program I compiled using just cl.exe from the SDK.

Comment: Using what you provided me, and a little bit of googling, gave me the following link: http://www.drdobbs.com/184416600

Answer (score 3):

That's not what /EH does, it merely controls what unwind handlers are emitted.  /EHsc ensures that destructors are called when C++ exceptions might be raised, /EHa ensures that they're called for any exceptions, including SEH.  Omitting /EH is what you want to cut down on handler overhead, the compiler omits the exception filters that get the destructors called on stack-allocated objects.  Change the destructor to this:

```
~CompilerFlagsTestExceptionConstructor() { 
    assert(!"Something is wrong with /EH");
}
```

If you want the look for unwanted try/catch code then you'll need to pay attention to

> warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc

Comment: VS2010 cl complains: Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/EH-'

Answer (score -1):

`/EHsc-` should do the trick (at least it does with msvc 14)

Comment: This yields the following warning though: `Warning D9025 overriding '/EHc' with '/EHc-'`

Comment: Per the Microsoft docs for the command line options for cl.exe, `/EHsc-` is equivalent to `/EHs`, which tells the compiler you want standard C++ exception handling but that it can assume `extern "C"` functions never throw.  This not what the question is asking for.